# UWP - Bugs on radio button

Tags: c#, uwp, radio-button

I have 3 pieces of radio button, like the picture below:
[image: image 1]

When I select the low option, then the high option is also checked (so there are 2 selections checked), like the image below:
[image: image 2]

But when the application is run, only the low option is selected. I want when the low option is selected, then only the low option is checked.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="highStack" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <RadioButton x:Name="highBtn" Margin="0,10,0,0" Content="High" FontSize="18" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="highSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="medStack" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <RadioButton x:Name="medBtn" Margin="0,15,0,0" Content="Medium" FontSize="18" IsChecked="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="medSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="lowStack" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <RadioButton x:Name="lowBtn" Margin="0,15,0,0" Content="Low" FontSize="18" IsChecked="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lowSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `GroupName` property:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="highStack" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton x:Name="highBtn" GroupName = "MyGroup" Margin="0,10,0,0" Content="High" FontSize="18" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="highSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel x:Name="medStack" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton x:Name="medBtn" GroupName = "MyGroup"  Margin="0,15,0,0" Content="Medium" FontSize="18" IsChecked="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="medSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel x:Name="lowStack" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton x:Name="lowBtn" GroupName = "MyGroup"  Margin="0,15,0,0" Content="Low" FontSize="18" IsChecked="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lowSize" Margin="30,5,0,0" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Radio buttons can be implicitly grouped (being inside the same `StackPanel` for example), or explicitly grouped (as above). See [Microsoft Guidelines on RadioButtons in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/radio-button).